# $\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Q \equiv \mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Q \oplus \mathbb Q$?

Tags: logic, model-theory, abelian-groups

Is it true that in signature $\{0,+,=\}$ of abelian groups $\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Q \equiv \mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Q \oplus \mathbb Q$? ($ M \equiv M'$ iff $Th (M) = Th (M')$). (Are $\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Q \oplus \mathbb Q$ elementarily equivalent?)

Comment: Are you asking whether these structures are elementarily equivalent?

Comment: Hint: how many distinct elements does $G / 2G$ have if $G = \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Q}$ versus if $G = \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Q} \oplus \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @AnginaSeng Clearly yes... the original post actually included the definition of $\equiv$! ($M\equiv M'$ iff $\text{Th}(M) = \text{Th}(M')$)

Comment: @DanielSchepler: You should post this as an answer.